# How to show image in ImageView ?

Tags: android, imageview

I want show a picture in ImageView. I have an ImageView with width=200dip and height=200dip and I want show large image in imageView. I want center of image set in ImageView and another parts not shows but when I scroll image, I see up or down image. I know, I should reduce size of image(reduce width and height) because I cant use height memory and when size of image is large, android cant shows image. Now, How can I reduce width and height of image until can use this and not show memory low? How can I set image in center of ImageView and scroll this for see up and down of image?

Comment: could you post your layout ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest better you use webview, with only one image tag and the path will be set dynamically, set the webview height and width according to your size and put larger image. so your image will scroll.

Comment: How i set an image to WebView?

Comment: Please more explain or sending a tutorial. Do you mean i use HTML? because when i searched, i see using html! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the very simple example to show image,

[Download Sample App](http://www.mkyong.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/Android-ImageView-Example.zip)

**1st thing you can do it by XML Layout**

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxHeight="80dip" <!-- Set your image size, remember: px and dip is different -->
    android:maxWidth="80dip" <!-- Set your image size -->
    android:src="@drawable/your_image"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

**if it is from file, and by programming !**

```
ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewId);
imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile("pathToImageFile"));
```

**if it is from drawables**

```
ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewId);
imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.imageFileId);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and sorry for my delay. I write this code in my program but some pictures not shows in ImageView(I think maybe size of this image is large) and some image shows in ImageView but not scroll, the image decrease width and height. I want width and height lager than ImageView and center of image set in ImageView and scroll ImageView for see another parts of Image. HOw can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
    //Using xml

     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/temp"
      />


  // By Codding

    ImageView iv = findViewById(R.id.iv);
    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.temp);
```